# Why don't doors stack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can understand the logic behind tools/armor not stacking in my inventory, due to each having their own wear & tear. However, I cannot understand why doors cannot stack. Does anyone have any reasonable logic or justification why they cannot?

Comment: Hey, for the record, this seems more of a 'why did they design it that way' question, which is off topic, and why I voted to close. Cant speak for the other voters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler answer would be that *this is the way it's programmed*. Many items have odd stacking rules like snowballs, mine carts, and eggs. I suppose this is meant to reflect how difficult it would be for a person to carry those items.

Comment: Fair enough. It just seems rather odd since gates and trap doors can both stack, while doors cannot.

Answer (score 4):

any item that takes more than one block cannot be stacked (bed, door, etc)

this seems to be a technical barrier because mod items that take up multiblock cannot be stacked either (like writing desk, scarecrow, cannon, etc)

Comment: Speaking from experience modding, there is no technical barrier. The game could as easily stack them as not, just by changing a single number in the code. The game and mod designers simply choose not to.